# How to stop mplayer playing through python

Tags: python, controls, mplayer

I am using my Raspberry Pi to play songs. I am trying to control the mplayer through a simple python programme. I have chosen python because I new to coding and have set up some simple imput driven menus to choose songs.

I found this code here to play the song :-

```
import os
SOUND = 'music.mp3'
command = 'mplayer %s 1>/dev/null 2>&1' % SOUND
os.system(command)
```

But I can't work out how to stop it part way through a track and return to my simple python menu to choose another option. Please help . . .

Comment: I guess you could try `os.system("pkill -9 mplayer")`

Comment: You could use `subprocess` and kill the process

Comment: or do it the right way as @PadraicCunningham suggests

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and kill the process whenever you want to end the song:

```
from subprocess import Popen

SOUND = 'music.mp3'
proc = Popen(['mplayer', '%s', '1>/dev/null', '2>&1',SOUND])
import time

time.sleep(3)
proc.kill()
```

Comment: Thank you so much works a treat, I can eat my dinner in peace now.

Comment: No worries, enjoy dinner